# Old computer socket disconnection, cleaning, and repair

Tags: connector, repair, computers, motherboard, cleaning

I have very old computers; from time to time the RAM disconnects. I remove the DIMMs, clean the sockets using Isopropyl alcohol many times until it works again.

It will be fine for few weeks, but I can't use both DIMMs even when I tried 10 times; one will not work.

I expected mechanical failure of one tiny connector and repeated heat/cold of the main board, is there any solution except simply cleaning?

Comment: Polypropylene is a plastic. Do you mean isopropanol?

Comment: Yes Isopropyl, sorry mistake

Comment: The traditional remedy for poor contact with card-edge connectors is to rub the contact area gently with a pink pencil eraser.

Comment: @PeterBennett hard to reach connectors inside the DIMM

Answer (score 1):

Try to resolder cold/cracked solder joints on the socket pins.